# Force all traffic through VPN

Tags: linux, vpn

I am using pfSense as a firewall, with its VPN functionality. The client I use is Shrew Soft VPN client. As it is a split tunnel, is there a way I can force all traffic through the VPN connection, i.e. so my external IP is always the pfSense box's one.

The reason I would like to do this is because the locations I access my servers from has DHCP assigned addresses via the ISP. I cannot afford a static IP, it isn't included in my package, but I lockdown my servers to only some IP's. When the ISP allocates a new IP, I am unable to access my servers through SSH. I have allowed the IP of the pfSense box as it is in a location which has a static IP.

How would I overcome this? Is there an alternative to trying to force the traffic through the VPN tunnel?

Comment: Use Dynamic DNS.

Comment: @tylerl please explain :)

Comment: Had a quick Google search, Ill look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Configure your routing table in linux.  Fairly straightforward, but will depend on your current configuration.

Type `route -n` to see your current routing table (on Mac OS X its `netstat -rn`).

Note the default route (the one that's destination `0.0.0.0`), that matches everything.  The basic way a routing table works is that traffic will match the most specific rule -- all it needs to know is where the first hop should go.  So a command like:

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 ppp0
sudo route add -net 1.2.3.0/24 ppp0
```

would add a line to your routing table that will take send any traffic going to an address matching those rules (all IP addresses that start with `10.*.*.*` for the first rule and all IP addresses that match `1.2.3.*` for the second rule) and send traffic to the ppp0 interface.  (Assuming its ppp0 interface).